# Use one Jenkinsfile or multiple Jenkinfiles

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are currently using Windows \ Jenkins 2.107.1 (no pipeline), and I am researching going to pipeline.  We have a nightly build job, that fetches from repositories, and submits and waits on other jobs.  I see 9 jobs running on the same Master node (we only have a master), at the same time.  I am not clear on if we should have one Jenkinsfile or multiple Jenkinsfiles. It will not be a multibranch pipeline, as we do not create test branches and then merge back to a master.  In the repository we have product1.0 branch, product2.0 branch etc, and build only one branch (the latest one).  While I do like the Blue Ocean editor, it is only for MultiBranch pipelines.

Do I combine all the jobs into one Jenkinsfile, or create multiple jenkins files for each of the existing jobs (Jenkinsfilestart, JenkinsfileFetchCVs, JenkinsFileFetchGit, Jenkinsfilenextjob,etc., and have one call the other)?.  Do I create all the old jobs as Jenkinsfiles, or scripts executed by the one master Jenkinsfile?  Do I do this in Declarative or script ?

Have set up Jenkins pipeline on test VM, but not clear on which way to go yet.

Looking for directions and\or examples.  Is there documentation on how to convert existing Jenkins non-pipeline systems?

I found this after doing the initial post...https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Convert+To+Pipeline+Plugin.
It does help a little in that it gives you some converted steps, but cannot convert all the steps, and will give comments in the pipeline script "//Unable to convert a build step referring to...please verify and convert manually if required."  There is an option "Recursively convert downstream jobs if any" and if you select that, it appears to add all the downstream jobs to the same pipeline script, and really confuses the job parameters.  There is also an option to "Commit JenkinsFile".  I will play with this some more, but it is not the be all and end all of converting to pipeline, and I still am not sure of whether I should be have one or more scripts.

Added 07/26/19 - 
Let’s see if I have my research to date correct…

A Declarative pipeline (Pipeline  Script from SCM), is stored in a Jenkinsfile in the repository.  Every time that this Jenkins job is executed, a fetch from the repository is done (to get the latest version of the Jenkinsfile).

A Pipeline script is stored as part of the config.xml file in the Jenkins\Jobs folder (it is not stored in the repository, or in a separate Jenkinsfile in the jobs folder).  There is a fetch from the repository only if the job requires it (you do not need to do a repository fetch to get the Pipeline script).

Besides our nightly product build, we also have other jobs.  I could create a separate Declarative Jenkinsfile for each of them (JenkinsfileA, JenkinsfileB, etc.) for each of the other jobs and store then in the repository also (in the same branch as the main Jenkinsfile), but  that would mean that every one of those additional jobs, to get the particular Jenkinsfile for that job, would also need to do a repository fetch (basically fetching\cloning the repository branch for each job, and have multiple versions of the repository branch unnecessarily downloaded to the workspace of each job).

That does not make sense to me (unless my understanding of things to date is incorrect).  Because the main product build does require a fetch every time it is run (to get any possible developer check-ins), I do not see a problem doing Declarative Jenkinsfile for that job.  For the other jobs (if we do not leave then for the time being in the classic (non-pipeline) format)), they will be Pipeline scripts.

Is there any way of (or plans for), being able to do Declarative pipeline without having to store in the repository and doing a fetch every time (lessening the need to become a Groovy developer)?  The Blue Ocean script editor appears to be an easier tool to use to create pipeline scripts, but it is only for MultiBranch pipelines (which we don’t do).

Serialization (restarting a job), is that only for when a node goes down, or can you restart a pipeline job (Declarative or Scripted), from any point if it fails?

I see that there are places to look to see what Jenkins plugin’s have been ported to pipeline, but is there anything that can be run to take a look at the classic jobs that you have, to determine up front which jobs are going to have problems being converted to pipeline?

08/02/19...
Studying and playing with pipelines.  I see that you can use Declarative in the Pipeline Scrip window, but it still stores it in the config.xml file.  And I have played with the combination of both Declarative and non Declarative in the same script.

I am trying to understand the Blue Ocean interface, the word "MultiBranch" is throwing me a little.  We do not create test branches, and them merge them back into the master.  In the repository, we have branches for each release of the product, and we rarely go back to previous branches\versions.  So, if I am working on branchV9 right now, do I also need a Jenkinsfile in the Master branch, or any other of the previous version branches?

I have been playing with Blue Ocean (which only does MultiBranch pipelines).  I am on a Windows system, Jenkins 2.176.2, and have all the latest Blue Ocean plugins as of today (1.18.0).  I am accessing a local Git repository (not GitHub), and am running into the following...

If I try to use use “c:\GitRepos\Pipelines1.git”, i get "not a valid name"...[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

[image: Image4e]

Why does it do this?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a single job that you would be executed on multiple branches (with possibly optional stages, depending on the branch name or tag or other) then you still could utilize multi branch pipeline.

In general I would say that paradigm shift focuses mainly on converting the old jobs to stages in order to automate your build process. If you would have semi/fully automated CI/CD flow this could look like

- Multibranch pipeline project (all branches) with the following stages (1st jenkinsfile)

  - build (all branches)
  - unit tests (all branches) publish report
  - publish artifacts (master and release branches)
  - build and publish docker (master and release branches)
  - deploy to test (master and release branches)
  - run integration tests (master and release branches)
  - deploy to staging (master and release branches) possibly ending with manual step if result of deployment was as expected
  - deploy to production (release branches)
- Pipeline job for nightly tests (other jenkinsfile), what's the result here? Would it break CI/CD flow?

Comment: I stated in my post that this will NOT be MultiBranch.  Each branch in the repository is for a separate release of the product and we rarely build a previous version.

Comment: Ok, I didn't intent to make you change your mind. Just describing how I understand the whole pipeline as code and jenkinsfiles. The idea to have multiple pipeline jobs point to one jenkinsfile is interesting. I wonder if there's a use case at all.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, it sound like you are saying that it if you have a classic Jenkins job that executes other jobs, that normally, when converting to pipeline, that all those downstream jobs are incorporated into the one and only Jenkinsfile.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you can have a new type of job - pipeline, just in jenkins. It doesn't make sense to accumulate more of those in a single jenkinsfile or to bound it to jenkinsfile on particular branch of a project. There are ideas like templates, automation of your build process etc. This should all be connected in a way. For example I would assume that this downstream job that you described is reused by several other jobs/branches/projects.